# R dividing dataset into ranged bins?

Tags: r, lattice

I am having some problems sorting my dataset into bins, that based on the numeric value of the data value. I tried doing it with the function `shingle` from the `lattice` which seem to split it accurately.

I can't seem to extract the desired output which is the knowledge how the data is divided into the predefined bins.  I seem only able to print it.

```
bin_interval = matrix(c(0.38,0.42,0.46,0.50,0.54,0.58,0.62,0.66,0.70,0.74,0.78,0.82,0.86,0.90,0.94,0.98,
                        0.40,0.44,0.48,0.52,0.56,0.60,0.64,0.68,0.72,0.76,0.80,0.84,0.88,0.92,0.96,1.0),
                        ncol = 2, nrow =  16)
bin_1 = shingle(data_1,intervals = bin_interval)
```

How do i extract the intervals which is outputted by the `shingle` function, and not only print it...

the intervals being the output:

```
Intervals:
    min  max count
1  0.38 0.40     0
2  0.42 0.44     6
3  0.46 0.48    46
4  0.50 0.52   251
5  0.54 0.56   697
6  0.58 0.60  1062
7  0.62 0.64  1215
8  0.66 0.68  1227
9  0.70 0.72  1231
10 0.74 0.76  1293
11 0.78 0.80  1330
12 0.82 0.84  1739
13 0.86 0.88  2454
14 0.90 0.92  3048
15 0.94 0.96  8936
16 0.98 1.00 71446
```

As an variable, that can be fed to another function.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using `cut` or `findInterval`?

Comment: Not exactly. The only output I am interested in is how the data is divided into these bins.  
The intervals has to be fed to an classifier.

Comment: You also have non-adjoining intervals. What about potential values between, for example, 0.40 and 0.42?

Comment: Oh... i completely overlooked that, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `shingle()` function returns the values using `attributes()`.

The levels are specifically given by `attr(bin_1,"levels")`.

So:

```
set.seed(1337)
data_1 = runif(100)

bin_interval = matrix(c(0.38,0.42,0.46,0.50,0.54,0.58,0.62,0.66,0.70,0.74,0.78,0.82,0.86,0.90,0.94,0.98,
                        0.40,0.44,0.48,0.52,0.56,0.60,0.64,0.68,0.72,0.76,0.80,0.84,0.88,0.92,0.96,1.0),
                        ncol = 2, nrow =  16)
bin_1 = shingle(data_1,intervals = bin_interval)

attr(bin_1,"levels")
```

This gives:

```
      [,1] [,2]
 [1,] 0.38 0.40
 [2,] 0.42 0.44
 [3,] 0.46 0.48
 [4,] 0.50 0.52
 [5,] 0.54 0.56
 [6,] 0.58 0.60
 [7,] 0.62 0.64
 [8,] 0.66 0.68
 [9,] 0.70 0.72
[10,] 0.74 0.76
[11,] 0.78 0.80
[12,] 0.82 0.84
[13,] 0.86 0.88
[14,] 0.90 0.92
[15,] 0.94 0.96
[16,] 0.98 1.00
```

**Edit**

The count information for each interval is only computed within the `print.shingle` method. Thus, you would need to run the following code:

```
count.shingle = function(x){
  l <- levels(x)
  n <- nlevels(x)
  int <- data.frame(min = numeric(n), max = numeric(n), 
                    count = numeric(n))
  for (i in 1:n) {
    int$min[i] <- l[[i]][1]
    int$max[i] <- l[[i]][2]
    int$count[i] <- length(x[x >= l[[i]][1] & x <= l[[i]][2]])
  }

  int
}

a = count.shingle(bin_1)
```

This gives:

```
> a 
   min  max count
1  0.38 0.40     0
2  0.42 0.44     1
3  0.46 0.48     3
4  0.50 0.52     1
5  0.54 0.56     2
6  0.58 0.60     2
7  0.62 0.64     2
8  0.66 0.68     4
9  0.70 0.72     1
10 0.74 0.76     3
11 0.78 0.80     2
12 0.82 0.84     2
13 0.86 0.88     5
14 0.90 0.92     1
15 0.94 0.96     1
16 0.98 1.00     2
```

where `a$min` is lower range, `a$max` is upper range, and `a$count` is the number within the bins.

Comment: what about the amount of that datapoint resides within these bins?

Comment: Count information is only computed within the `print.shingle` method.

Comment: ....Well the purpose of all this was to extract this information.. Other options?

Comment: See above for the `count.shingle()` function.